# Need a jquery (or something else) plugin for horiz/vert scrollable table that supports mutiple header rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a html table that is dynamically generated using xsl from a stored proc, and all column sizes/classes etc come from meta-data in the db.  I need a plugin of some kind that will enable horizontal and vertical scrolling and be able to handle multiple header rows.

So far I've tried quite a few but most either don't have horizontal scrolling or don't seem to support multiple header rows.  Both features are essential.  What would you use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the plugin here [fixedtableheader jquery plugin](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx) as it was the only thing I found that could handle my badly formatted html.  Despite being a little unusual in design it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

try JqGrid
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

try with this....
http://www.datatables.net/

i m doing the same thing with this plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried datatables but it won't handle the tables I've got.  For example, one has something like this <tr><td colspan="26">XX</td></tr> and it stops datatables from working

Comment: would you show me your html so that i can tell you how to render your table which suits to dataTable